# Is there any way to check if an object is a type of enum in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
enum Direction {
    Up = 1,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}

if (typeof Direction === 'enum') {
    // doesn't work
}
```

Any way to check if the above is in fact an `enum`?

Comment: Why do you want to check if it's an enum? What do you mean by "check"--check at run-time? But enums are a compile-time construct.

Comment: Check before compile time. As to why: I want to convert the object to an array and want to know whether I need to remove half the object's properties. I was wondering if there was a very clean way to know if the object is of this type of data structure before attempting the conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums are compiled into simple objects that have two way mapping:

```
name => value
value => name
```

So the enum in your example compiles to:

```
var Direction;
(function (Direction) {
    Direction[Direction["Up"] = 1] = "Up";
    Direction[Direction["Down"] = 2] = "Down";
    Direction[Direction["Left"] = 3] = "Left";
    Direction[Direction["Right"] = 4] = "Right";
})(Direction || (Direction = {}));
```

So the `typeof` of `Direction` is a plain `"object"`.
There's no way of knowing in runtime that the object is an enum, not without adding more fields to said object.

---

#### Edit

Sometimes you don't need to try to workaround a problem with a specific approach you have, you can maybe just change the approach.
In this case, you can use your own object:

```
interface Direction {
    Up: 1,
    Down: 2,
    Left: 3,
    Right: 4
}
const Direction = {
    Up: 1,
    Down: 2,
    Left: 3,
    Right: 4
} as Direction;
```

Or:

```
type Direction = { [name: string]: number };
const Direction = { ... } as Direction;
```

Then turning this object into an array should be simple.

Comment: RIght. But is there a way to detect before compile time? Is there a way that typescript might detect such a thing?

Comment: I suppose it might be possible to write a function that would inspect the compiled object's properties for their symmetry.

Comment: Can you please add an example to your question for the use case you have in mind? I fail to see how that can be beneficial.

Comment: I want to write a function that will convert the object to an array but *if it's an enum* also remove half its properties.

Comment: I'll just cheat and keep only keys that are integers.

Comment: You can check this symmetry as you suggested, but maybe you just don't need to use enums in this case. Check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks for the revision. I'd say your approach is not high level enough though, I don't want to check if the object is an instance of `Direction`, I want to check if it's a data dictionary like data structure, like an enum.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that part. **But** if you use this as your enum then you won't need to make that distinction to begin with because then your function could just convert it without worrying about removing half the props

Comment: Right, so you're basically suggesting using a [Type Alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to define the dictionary and check for that. It's an interesting approach. Thanks.

Comment: Well, kinda. Typescript enums define two things: type and value. In my suggestion you use the same identifier (`Direction`) to define the type (using type alias or interface) and then the value (the `const` part).

Comment: Here you use a type alias if I'm not mistaken: `type Direction = { [name: string]: number };`

Comment: Yes, but above that I use an interface.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, here's a method that will determine if an object is an enum:

```
  isEnum(instance: Object): boolean {
    let keys = Object.keys(instance);
    let values = [];

    for (let key of keys) {
      let value = instance[key];

      if (typeof value === 'number') {
        value = value.toString();
      }

      values.push(value);
    }

    for (let key of keys) {
      if (values.indexOf(key) < 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: it accepts null in its current state,  but other than that, very useful, thank you!

Comment: This is quite a slow operation just to get a trivial type.

Comment: This does not work with string enums because they are not reverse mapped: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#string-enums